# What are the best practices for calculating statistics in REST API applications

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, statistics

I am trying to make a service that will calculate statistics for each month.

I did smth like this:

```
public Map<String, BigDecimal> getStatistic() {
        List<Order> orders = orderService.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "creationDate")).toList();
        SortedMap<String, BigDecimal> statisticsMap = new TreeMap<>();
        MathContext mc = new MathContext(3);
        for (Order order : orders) {
            List<FraudDishV1Response> dishesOfOrder = order.getDishIds()
                    .stream()
                    .map(dishId -> dishV1Client.getDishById(dishId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            BigDecimal total = calculateTotal(dishesOfOrder);
            String date = order.getCreatedDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM"));
            statisticsMap.merge(date, total, (a, b) -> a.add(b, mc));
        }
        return statisticsMap;
    }
```

But it takes a long time if there are lots of etries in the database.
Are there any best practices for working with statistics in REST API applications?

And also I'd like to know if it is a good way to save the statistics in a separate repository? It will save time for calculating statistics, but during creating a record in the database, you will also have to update the statistics db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did't stop and made several solutions step by step...

**Step 1:** Use `streams`. Before that, calculating statistics for 10,000 OrderEntities records took 18 seconds. Now it has accelerated to 14 seconds.

**Step 2:** Using `parallelStream` instead of `streams`. Parallel streams accelerated the calculation of statistics to 6 seconds! I was even surprised.

```
public SortedMap<String, BigDecimal> getStatisticsByParallelStreams() {
        List<OrderEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orderService.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdDate")).forEach(orders::add);

        MathContext mc = new MathContext(3);
        return orders.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                order -> order.getCreatedDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM")),
                order -> calculateTotal(order.getDishIds()
                        .parallelStream()
                        .map(dishId -> dishV1Client.getDishById(dishId))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())),
                (a, b) -> a.add(b, mc),
                TreeMap::new
        ));
    }
```

**Step 3:** Optimizing requests to another microservice. I connected the **JProfiler** to the app and I have found out that I offen do extra requests to the another microservice. After it firstly I made a request to receive all Dishes, and then during calculating statistics, I use a recieved List of Dishes.
And thus I speeded it up to **1.5 seconds**!:

```
public SortedMap<String, BigDecimal> getStatisticsByParallelStreams() {
        List<OrderEntity> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orderService.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "createdDate")).forEach(orders::add);

        List<FraudDishV1Response> dishes = dishV1Client.getDishes();

        MathContext mc = new MathContext(3);
        return orders.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                order -> order.getCreatedDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM")),
                order -> calculateTotal(order.getDishIds()
                        .parallelStream()
                        .map(dishId -> getDishResponseById(dishes, dishId))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())),
                (a, b) -> a.add(b, mc),
                TreeMap::new
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With your approach you'll eventually run out of memory while trying to load huge amount of data from database. You could do processing in batches but then again it will only get you so far. Ideally any kind of statistical data or on demand reporting would be served by long running scheduled jobs which will periodically do processing in the background and generate the desired data for you. You could dump the result in a table and then serve it from there via an API.

Another approach is to do real time processing. If you could develop a streaming pipeline in your application then I would highly suggest you may explore [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) project.